# difftime returns strange value on particular date

Tags: c++, c, time, mingw, ctime

I don't understand why difftime returns a strange value, so here is the dataset and the code I am using.

Code :

```
struct tm currentTime;
currentTime.tm_year = 2014 - 1900;
currentTime.tm_mon = 9 - 1;
currentTime.tm_mday = 6;
currentTime.tm_hour = 23;
currentTime.tm_min = 59;
currentTime.tm_sec = 0;
currentTime.tm_wday = 7 - 1;

struct tm previousTime;
previousTime.tm_year = 2014 - 1900;
previousTime.tm_mon = 9 - 1;
previousTime.tm_mday = 6;
previousTime.tm_hour = 23;
previousTime.tm_min = 58;
previousTime.tm_sec = 0;
previousTime.tm_wday = 7 - 1;

cout << difftime(mktime(&currentTime), mktime(&previousTime)) << endl;
```

This prints :

```
3660
```

Any ideas why I get this value ?
I should get 60, as there is a one minute difference.
I tried with some other values, and they all work.. 
I'm using CodeBlocks with mingw.

EDIT : Answer : use of tm_isdst solved the problem ! Bloody DST :P

```
struct tm currentTime;
currentTime.tm_year = 2014 - 1900;
currentTime.tm_mon = 9 - 1;
currentTime.tm_mday = 6;
currentTime.tm_hour = 23;
currentTime.tm_min = 59;
currentTime.tm_sec = 0;
currentTime.tm_wday = 7 - 1;
currentTime.tm_isdst = - 1;

struct tm previousTime;
previousTime.tm_year = 2014 - 1900;
previousTime.tm_mon = 9 - 1;
previousTime.tm_mday = 6;
previousTime.tm_hour = 23;
previousTime.tm_min = 58;
previousTime.tm_sec = 0;
previousTime.tm_wday = 7 - 1;
previousTime.tm_isdst = - 1;

cout << difftime(mktime(&currentTime), mktime(&previousTime)) << endl;
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that this doesn't compile [because the member names are incorrect](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm), once you fix the errors [you get 60 as expected.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af76e98edee8cdbb). tl;dr; cannot repro.

Comment: @Borgleader Yes sorry I didn't copy well my program on SO. I updated it with the new values, and I still get a strange value : 3660

Comment: So you actually have `previousTime.tm_hour = 22;` in your code.

Comment: @AntonSavin No, I did the test with the exact same code than Borgleader posted, and I got 3660 (I just changed the years with a minus 1900 instead of 1990). It might come from mingw ?

Comment: It's more likely to be timezone related. Did you notice that your output is precisely one day out from what you wanted it to be?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually it's an hour out from what I want, that's really really strange..

Comment: Daylight saving time issues?

Comment: Does your date cross the DST border?

Comment: @Hawknight: Haha oops yeah an hour not a day. So the problem is likely even more simple than I thought.

Comment: @Hawknight initialize `tm_isdst` field of both variables and see what happens

Comment: `mktime()` require 7 fields to be set, y-m-d, h:m:s and `is_dst`.  Set to -1 if unsure.  `tm_wday` is irrelevant.

Comment: I initialized to zero tm_isdt in both, and it returns the correct time ! Thanks guys ! I then had a look and previousTime had a strange value set, while currentTime didn't, that was the problem !

Comment: @Hawknight if you know DST was not applicable, using 0 is fine, otherwise use -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before calling `mktime()`, typically 7 fields of `struct tm` need to be set.  As OP only set 6 of those, uninitialized data was in field `tm_isdst` causing an unexpected shift of 3600 seconds.

```
struct tm currentTime;
currentTime.tm_year = 2014 - 1900;
currentTime.tm_mon = 9 - 1;
currentTime.tm_mday = 6;
currentTime.tm_hour = 23;
currentTime.tm_min = 59;
currentTime.tm_sec = 0;

currentTime.tm_isdst = -1;  // **
// currentTime.tm_wday = 7 - 1; 

mktime(&currentTime);
```

Recommend to zero-fill `struct tm` as in `struct tm currentTime = { 0 };` to insure all fields are specified as `struct tm` may contain fields in addition to the 9: `int tm_sec tm_min tm_hour tm_mday tm_mon tm_year tm_wday tm_yday tm_isdst`.

---

Notes:

The original values in `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` are ignored and re-calculated by `mktime()`.  The other fields' original values are not restricted to their normal range and are recalculated too.

** a positive or zero value for `tm_isdst` causes the `mktime` function to presume initially that Daylight Saving Time, respectively, is or is not in effect for the specified time. A negative value causes it to attempt to determine whether Daylight Saving Time is in effect for the specified time.

Comment: Great explanation here. Basically, it's safer to zero-fill the variable before using it ?

Comment: @Hawknight Since `struct tm` has at least the well-defined 9 fields, portable code should not risk leaving others uninitialized.  In general, when using structures not-of-your-making, best to zero them before using.   Had your code zero-filled, things would have been as expected, except near DST shifts.  Without digging deeper, use `tm_isdst = 0 or 1` when you know the setting, else use `-1`.