# How to compare date and time, given in string format?

Tags: c++, c++11, time, c++17

I wonder to know how I can compare date and time in a string format in C++?
In other words my question is that how can I implement the compare function for the following class using libraries?

```
class DateTime {
  private: 
   string date =;
   string time ;
  public :
     DateTime (string d, string t) :date (d), time(t) {
     }
     DateTime diff (DateTime t1, DateTime t2) {
     //?
     }
};
```

Let's assume I call it as below

```
DateTime from ("2020-11-09", "06:22:30");
DateTime to ("2021-04-03", "23:54:13");
Date diff = to.diff (from ,to);
```

This is just an example, any suggestion for comparing a date and time is appreciated. The constraint I have is that date and time are given in string format, it would be great if I can return their differences in second or in similar string format shown above.

I have tried this [struct](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_date_time.htm) in VScode, but I get the compilation error that it cannot recognize the `time_t` variable members.

Comment: Please show a [mre] of the code you tried and the exact error message you receive

Comment: There is the `<ctime>` and `<chrono>` library if you want to look at, however neither of them support converting custom text format to time/date objects. You would need to create them yourself. (I'm sure there are good libraries out there you can look for though)

Comment: With further digging, seems like you can use `chrono::from_stream` or `chrono::parse` to customize a parser for your `chrono::duration` type with C++20. I don't have it in hand to test it however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i could finalize it after searching different references.
First i got some random wrong results while testing with around 8000 inputs, but i realized one field that i commented in code should be updated before calling mktime() function.

```
class Time {
   private:
      time_t _timeType;
      struct tm buf;
      struct tm * _timeinfo  = &buf;
      string _timeStr;
      string _dateStr;

 public:
      Time (string time, string date) : _timeStr(time),_dateStr(date) { // YYYY-MM-DD , HH:MM:SS
           int hr =  stoi(time.substr(0,2));
           int min = stoi(time.substr(3,2));
           int sec = stoi(time.substr(6,2));

           int yr = stoi(date.substr(0,4));
           int mon = stoi(date.substr(5,2));
           int day = stoi(date.substr(8,2));  

            _timeinfo->tm_hour = hr;
            _timeinfo->tm_min = min;
            _timeinfo->tm_sec = sec;
            _timeinfo->tm_mday = day;
            _timeinfo->tm_mon = mon-1; // because it is in range of [0:11]
            _timeinfo->tm_year = yr;
           /*I updated this field to prevent strange reports based folloing this recommendation
           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788470/difftime-returns-strange-value-on-particular-date
           */ 
            _timeinfo->tm_isdst = -1;
            _timeType = mktime(_timeinfo);   
      }

      void compareTime (Time* t) {  
         cout<<_timeStr<<" "<< _dateStr<<" "<<t->_timeStr <<" "<<t->_dateStr<<" "<<difftime(_timeType, t->_timeType)<<endl;
      }
};
```